# Is there a way to download an artifact from the latest release on GitHub?

Tags: github, deployment, continuous-integration

On GitHub I can access a release with particular version with a link like `https://github.com/markvincze/golang-build-test/releases/tag/hello-v6`.

I can download its artifacts from that release with `https://github.com/markvincze/golang-build-test/releases/download/hello-v6/filename`.

I can also access the latest release with `https://github.com/markvincze/golang-build-test/releases/latest`

**Question**: Is there a way to directly download an artifact from the latest release?
I tried `https://github.com/markvincze/golang-build-test/releases/download/latest/filename`, but it doesn't work, and I couldn't find anything in the docs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could determine the latest tag using, for example, the [HTTP `HEAD` request method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods):

```
HEAD https://github.com/markvincze/golang-build-test/releases/latest
```

At the time of writing this returns a response including the following two headers:

```
Status: 302 Found
Location: https://github.com/markvincze/golang-build-test/releases/tag/hello-v6
```

Using this you should now be able to submit a second request using the appropriate tag.

See [Wikipedia's writeup of HTTP 302 for details](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302).

Another option would be to use the [Get the latest release](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/releases/#get-the-latest-release) endpoint provided by the GitHub API, and then similarly follow up with a second request. In this case the `tag_name` key from the response will be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the info! (I was hoping to be able to use a direct link, since I'll have to do this from both a bash and a PowerShell script, and I wanted to avoid sending the HTTP requests and extracting the tag name... but nothing can be perfect, right? :))

Comment: I've written a blog post about how URLs to the latest artifacts can be determined with shell script and PowerShell: http://blog.markvincze.com/download-artifacts-from-a-latest-github-release-in-sh-and-powershell/